# jquery - issue getting script tags after two .filter()'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter, tags

I have an ajax response that want to parse for  tags, and I only want to find script tags within a specific div id. The below will capture and run each javascript within the page:

```
success: function(data) {
    var dom = $(data);
    dom.filter('script').each(function(){
        var obj = $(this);                                          
        $('#my_div').append(obj);
    });
},
```

When I try to filter first by div id, and then by script it does not append anything. I have access to the reponse html obviously, and I can see that there should be multiple  tags in the 'js_outer_div' div:

```
var dom = $(data);
dom.filter('js_outer_div').filter('script').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);                                          
    $('#my_div').append(obj);
});
```

Unfortunately I have no control over the response html. Is there a way to filter first by div and then by script like I am wanting?

EDIT: sample html response:

```
... 
<div id="i9-content-div">
<script xmlns:efactions="http://www.enginframe.com/2009/efactions" xmlns:grid="http://www.enginframe.com/2000/GRID" type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are correctly selecting in the filter? Isn't it `dom.filter('#js_outer_div')` or `dom.filter('.js_outer_div')` with classes. I am pretty sure though.

Answer (score 1):

> I can see that there should be multiple tags in the 'js_outer_div' div

If `js_outer_div` is a class name then the `filter` method should be:

```
dom.filter('.js_outer_div')...
```

But no, it doesn't solve the problem. `filter` method filters the top level elements in the collection. A jQuery collection is not flat, it preserves the element hierarchy.  You should use the `find` method. As `find` method selects the descendants of the wrapper element in the collection, you can generate a `div` element and use the `html` method for setting it's content using the `data` variable. Now the `find` method works whether the target `div.js_outer_div` is a top level element or not.

```
$('<div/>').html(data).find('.js_outer_div script').each(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like this is working, but I can't tell if it is filtering the right scripts or not. is there anything i can print to check what script i am running? Maybe a console log of the script text?

Comment: @EvanDefend You are welcome. `console.log($('<div/>').html(data).find('.js_outer_div script'))`  logs the selected `script`s.

Comment: Looked at it this morning and very confused by the results. It seems like the very line `$('<div/>').html(data).find('#js_outer_div script');` is causing every script tag in `data` to execute (confused though because in console there is a single 'GET' for each script, never seen this before.) The .each function itself appears to do nothing, I put an alert() in there but it never fires. Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` instead of `filter`.

```
var dom = $(data);
dom.find('js_outer_div script').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);                                          
    $('#my_div').append(obj);
});
```

Now this actually wont select anything unless you have a `<js_outer_div>` tag somewhere. Presumably you need to change `js_outer_div` to `.js_outer_div` or `#js_outer_div` in the find statement.

Comment: js noob here, sorry for forgetting to mention that I want to find/filter by div id. I tried: `dom.find('#js_outer_div script').each(function(){` with and without the `#`, and it still doesn't appear to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post an example of the data returned?

Comment: I edited my post to include some example html response lines. After logging `dom.find('#js_outer_div script')` , it looks like it returns an object with a 'prevObject' that contains all scripts in `data` (not just the ones within the 'id=js_outer_div' div), as well as the js_outer_div div. Very sorry that I am not better at debugging , like I said I am new to js.

Comment: After messing around, It looks like `dom.find('#js_outer_div')` is returning the correct div, but stripping out the script tags.